# drop down menu selection using console doesn't trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set value for field with help of console,but when I am doing this it is not triggering the event which should occur when I select option from drop down list.It only shows selected value in drop down menu field,but event doesn't occur.

**I am using following query on console:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("input-text")[5].value="string:100#2#######"
```

**Following is code for HTML select:-**

```
<select class="input-text ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="selectedSname" ng-show="snames != null &amp;&amp; (name712 != null &amp;&amp; name712 != '')" ng-options="sname.surveypins as sname.fullname for sname in snames">
  <option selected="selected"></option>
  <option label="1" value="string:55#9####### ">abc</option>
  <option label="2" value="string:100#2####### ">xyz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("input-text"))[5].XXXXXXXXXX      what should be XXXXXXXXX for selection can you help me @yash

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `onchange` method manually like:

HTML:

```
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('test').onchange = function () {
    alert('changed');
}

document.getElementById('test').value = "2";
document.getElementById('test').onchange();
```

A working JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/3g4ruz7h/)

---

And because you are using AngularJS, we have to choose the options by angular way like this:

```
$scope.selectedSname = "string:100#2#######";
```

So angular will catch your change and fire the digest loop, which will fire the change event.

Comment: Thank you.@MuhmmadAref Can you plese provide me angularJS query to do this.